# Redirect to the front page if the user access the website with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to know if the user access the website from the domain it self ("http://mydomain.com") or access it using such url ("http://mydomain.com/about") and redirect him to the front page

I tried this code and I put it in the page.tpl.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !="/"){header( 'Location: http://www.mydomain.com' );}
```

but if the user click any link on the home page its keep redirect him.

Please help

Comment: What does `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on main page print?

Comment: @Fabio I tried to print it, its return "/"

Comment: Try `ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') === '')`

Comment: edited mined answer, does it work now for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code
  in this i am  using regular expression to find that that if the request came from your site  or not

```
 if(preg_match('#^https?\://(?:www\.)?mydomain\.com/?$#',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
   //matched

 }else{

   // redirect to other  index page
 }
```

IT will work for you